# How to format a USB drive showing unallocated space?

Tags: partitioning, usb, gparted

I'm having trouble formatting my 16GB USB stick. I've gone through most of the previous questions on this topic, but I'm not able to do it. **Badblocks** showed no error, **Gparted** is unable to create partition table, and the **Disks** tool showing unallocated space in front of **Contents**.

I just want to format it as I have no important data in it.

Comment: Is there any error that `gparted` is giving when you try to create a partition?  Feel free to add screenshots and text of things that you have tried.  More details would help us help you figure out why you can't format your USB drive.

Comment: You can analyze the problem and try to solve it according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035).

Comment: I had to delete the comment considering this "family friendly site".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Do a search for using the non-graphical ***parted*** command for the task. I will not repeat the steps here, as you can easily find it. Basically, you put a partition on the drive followed by a file system. Then using the ***chmod*** command, give read and write permissions to the drive.